# subversion include directory exclude files

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to include a directory when I do my imports but exclude any files that might be in it.  how can this be done?

ie: include **cache** dir, but exclude all the cache files in it.

in my global-ignores I have tried *cache* and *cache/**,  the former just excluded the entire cache dir - expected.  and the later included everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" ./mycachefolder/
```

In eclipse you would rightclick the folder and select "add property". Simple add a * then.

Answer (score 0):

During an import you can simply control by deleting or moving the files from the location you don't like to import.

The simplest solution is to move the files to a backup location do the import and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/shuber/svnignore - git style ignores with subversion